# Google chrome document.body.scrollTop always returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scroll, chromium

In Google chrome document.body.scrollTop always returns 0.

I try

```
  if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
    st = window.pageYOffset;
  } else if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
    st = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  } else {
    st = document.body.scrollTop;
  }
```

But not working.
document.body.scrollTop is working in firefox.

Even in chrome console when i this code in console it is not working.

```
enter code here
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: 50
  }, 500);
```

Comment: I also have this problem. Works in FF and Safari. It was working about 2 months ago. I think there's a bug maybe?

Answer (score 10):

I hit this as well. According to this issue this behavior changed between Chrome 60 and Chrome 61:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=766938

From what I have read the new behavior is actually more standards compliant. The suggested fix from comment #5 for that issue is:

> If you are looking for an interoperable way of querying scrollTop you can use the window.scrollY attribute or doing something like document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop

Answer (score 0):

I am using React,
I found that root element #root has css rule position: fixed;
if remove the rule, scrollTop could return correct values.

```
getScrollTop = () => {
        let scrollTop = 0;

        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
            scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        } else if (document.body) {
            scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
        }

        return scrollTop;
    }
```