# Scroll Effect doesn't work on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, scroll

I have a scroll effect that changes the colour of the background by finding the users position on the page and using that to set the colour. This works fine on safari and in Atom Html Previewer however when I checked it on chrome it didn't work. 
My website is [harry-day.con](http://harry-day.com)

Any suggestions on why it doesn't work or how to fix it? I tried modifying the JS slightly but nothing worked.

Here is the JavaScript I am using:

```
function scroll(){
    var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;
    var height = html.scrollHeight - html.clientHeight;
    var color = Math.round((body.scrollTop / height) * 255);
    body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+color+","+color+","+color+")";
}
```

Edit:  I tried using `var color = Math.round((html.scrollTop / height) * 255);` however now it does not work when I tested it locally in Safari.

Comment: Looks like the issue is that `document.body.scrollTop` is `0` when you scroll.

Comment: Which is the current behaviour in chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46481780/8583739

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464876/javascript-get-window-x-y-position-for-scroll) for a cross-browser way of getting current scroll position:

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
var top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);
```

```js
function scroll(){
    var body = document.body;
    var doc = document.documentElement;
    var top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);
    var height = doc.scrollHeight - doc.clientHeight;
    var color = Math.round((top / height) * 255);
    body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+color+","+color+","+color+")";
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', scroll);
```

```css
body {
  height: 1400px;
}
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, now it doesn't work in Safari but works in Chrome. Any other suggestions? Thanks anyway

Comment: @HarryDay can you check now?