# jQuery difference between document and body

Tags: jquery, document, scrolltop, document-body

As a jQuery statement,

```
$(document).scrollTop(200);
```

works on Chrome. However,

```
$("body").scrollTop(200);
```

doesn't.
Can I know the difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google chrome document.body.scrollTop always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43717316/google-chrome-document-body-scrolltop-always-returns-0)

Comment: Body is an element really and you can set dimensions on it. Can even be zero height yet overflow it's content. document is the absolute object that gets rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document` and `body` are different things.

`document` refers to the current 'document' been loaded into the browser's tab.
This document contains everything there is for your page, the document also contains the body element inside it.

On the other hand the body is just a plain html element, a little bit special compared to a `div` or a `span`, but still it is only an element within the document.